# Crystal Report C# add-on logonfailed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I'm too getting too stuck trying to solve this issue I try to  print directly value from my SAP add-on using C# in Visual Studio 2010 it's return for me this error:

> 'logonfailed'

Here is my code :

```
try
        {
            DataTable matable = new DataTable();
            DataSet madataset = new DataSet();
            SqlConnection maconnexion = new SqlConnection();

            maconnexion.ConnectionString = Menu.connectionString_formatsql;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = "select oitm.ItemCode ,OITM .ItemName ,OITM .CodeBars,ITM1.Price,@codebars " +
                      " from OITM,ITM1 where OITM .ItemCode=ITM1 .ItemCode" +
                      " and OITM.ItemCode =@itemCode" +
                      " and ITM1 .PriceList = @pricelist  ";

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@codebars", SqlDbType.VarChar );
            //cmd.Parameters["@codebars"].Value = get_codebarre_dessin();

            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@itemCode", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            //cmd.Parameters["@itemCode"].Value = this.EditText1.Value;

            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@pricelist", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
            //cmd.Parameters["@pricelist"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(this.ComboBox0.Value);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@codebars", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@codebars"].Value = get_codebarre_dessin();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@itemCode", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@itemCode"].Value = this.EditText1.Value;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pricelist", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters["@pricelist"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(this.ComboBox0.Value);

            cmd.Connection = maconnexion;

            if (maconnexion.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                maconnexion.Open();
            }
            SqlDataAdapter madataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       //     SqlCommandBuilder madatabuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(madataadapter );


            matable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            madataset.Tables.Add(matable);

         

         


            ReportDocument  report = new ReportDocument();
        
            report.Load("BARCODE.rpt");
            report.Refresh();

            report.DataSourceConnections.Clear();

            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in report.Database.Tables)
            {

                TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
                
                MessageBox.Show( tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName );
               MessageBox.Show( tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName);
                 MessageBox.Show(tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID);
                 MessageBox.Show(tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password.ToString());
                 MessageBox.Show(tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity.ToString() );
                //table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo);
                //table.Location = Menu.company.CompanyDB + ".dbo." + table.Name.ToString();  
            }


            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in report.Database.Tables)
            {

                TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
                tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.AllowCustomConnection = true;
                tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = Menu.company.Server;
                tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = Menu.company.CompanyDB;
                //tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = Menu.company.UserName;
                //tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = Menu.company.Password;
                tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = Menu .company.DbUserName;
                tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = Menu.company.DbPassword;
                tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false ;
                table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo);
                table.Location = Menu.company.CompanyDB + ".dbo." + table.Name.ToString();
            }


            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in report.Database.Tables)
            {

                TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;

                MessageBox.Show(tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName);
                MessageBox.Show(tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName);
                MessageBox.Show(tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID);
                MessageBox.Show(tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity.ToString());
                //table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo);
                //table.Location = Menu.company.CompanyDB + ".dbo." + table.Name.ToString();  
            }

            report.SetDataSource(matable);
            report.SetDatabaseLogon(Menu.company.DbUserName, Menu.company.DbPassword);
            PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();
            PrintDialog pdialog = new PrintDialog();
            pdialog.PrinterSettings = settings;
            pdialog.AllowPrintToFile = true;
            pdialog.AllowSomePages = true;
            pdialog.UseEXDialog = true;

            // ParameterFields parameterFields = report.ParameterFields;
            //report.SetParameterValue(0, this.ComboBox0.Value);
            //report.SetParameterValue(1, EditText1.Value.ToString());
            //report.SetParameterValue(2, get_codebarre_dessin());
            report.SetParameterValue(2, this.ComboBox0.Value);
            report.SetParameterValue(1, EditText1.Value.ToString());
            report.SetParameterValue(0, get_codebarre_dessin());

            report.PrintOptions.PrinterName = ComboBox1.Value;
            //report.PrintToPrinter(settings, new PageSettings() { }, false);
      
            report.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 1, System.Convert.ToInt32(EditText0.Value));


            maconnexion.Close();

        }

        catch (LogOnException engEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Logon Parameters. Check your user name and password." + engEx.ErrorID);
        }
        catch (DataSourceException engEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred while connecting to the database.");
        }
        catch (EngineException engEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(engEx.Message);
        }
```

Comment: check connection to your server

Comment: there is no problem with my connection cuze the table return rows also if u check my code before i sent logon parametre to  my report i read it by messagebox before and after there is no diff